# Fine-tuned PLBart model generates sequences of repeated tokens

Tags: deep-learning

I'm fine-tuning PLBart model to generate unit-tests for given Java method (I'm using Methods2Test dataset). In tokenization I've set `max_length=510`.

Here are the trainer arguments:

```
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="fine_tuned_m2t_4",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    per_device_train_batch_size=6,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=6,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    learning_rate=1e-4,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    warmup_ratio=0.2,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    dataloader_num_workers=6,
    fp16=True
)
```

And here are a few examples of values the model generates:

```
'try222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222',
'trylashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlashlash'.
```

Interestingly, the **training loss** from the latest checkpoint (the one that generated those sequences) is **0.166200** and **validation loss is 0.324217**. And both of those sequences were generated for input that was in the training dataset.

I've tried removing `fp16=True` setting, but the results were pretty much the same. I've tried setting `learning_rate=1e-5`, the results didn't change.

By the way, ignore the number of epochs, I've trained the model for longer than that, I just kept restarting from latest checkpoint and experimenting with training arguments.